# How to calculate and display possible graphs from 3 directed branches?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have 3 directed branches and I want to create all possible graphs that can be created from these branches with the condition that each branch is used once.

**Q1:** How can I do create and graph them?

[image]

Here are some example graphs:
[image]

**Q2:** Same as Q1 but now add one more condition that the branch `a` and branch `b` are connected as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is a branch here, and how is it implemented?

Comment: @thorimur it's something like this `Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1}]`

Comment: hmm ok, so are you asking for all possible graphs with 3 directed edges? if so do you have any constraint on the number of vertices? also are the edges and vertices labeled?

Comment: @thorimur yes, all possible graphs with 3 directed edges. I don't have any constraint in the number of vertices but from 3 branches there is a maximum of 6 vertices. I labeled edges to make it clear that they're different. I think you could also label the vertices if an edge.

Comment: @thorimur sorry for the confusion, I think the edge's vertices should be labelled to make it clear that the arrow is only one direction from A -> B not B -> A for example if A, B are the vertices of the edge.

Comment: ok gotcha. so if our vertices are `1,2,3,4,5,6`, is the edge `a`  from `1` to `2` different from `a` from `4` to `6`, for example?

Comment: @thorimur for example 1 and 2 are two vertices of a then the edge a is always from 1 to 2. I edited and added some examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
edges = {"A" -> "B", "C" -> "D", "E" -> "F"};

styledlabelededges = MapThread[Labeled[Style[#, #2], #3] &, 
   {edges, 
   {Red, Green, Blue}, 
   Style[#, 16, Background -> White] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}}];

g0 = Graph[styledlabelededges, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Medium, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[vContract]
vContract[g_] := Graph @@ 
  ({EdgeList[g], Options[g]} /. #[[2]] -> #[[1]] /. #[[1]] -> #) &

vreplacements = {{"B", "E"}, {"B", "F"}, {"B", "C"}, {"A", "D"}};

Grid[Partition[vContract[g0] /@ vreplacements, 2], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: When B, E are contracted, the branch `a` could be disconnected as in your plot but it can also connect to any other node. How can I do that? How can I plot all cases also when 3 branches are connected? I think you mean to apply contract in series?

Comment: @anhnha, corrected the labels and styles.

Comment: your image shows the contracted nodes with two letters like `{B, E}` but it doesn't appear when I run it.

Comment: @anhnha, please try the current version.

Comment: nice, the code is complex but I'll try to reprocedure it.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a brute force solution, but it is easy to understand:

This is the starting graph:

```
g0 = Graph[{"a" -> "b", "c" -> "d", "e" -> "f"}];
```

You want to contract vertices in all possible ways. For simplicity, we will use `IGVertexContract` from IGraph/M, as it can handle multiple contractions simultaneously.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
```

Contracting the two endpoints of an existing edge (such as `a -> b`) is not allowed:

```
vertices = VertexList[g0]

disallowed = Partition[vertices, 2]
(* {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}} *)
```

These are the allowed contractions:

```
possibleContractions = Complement[Subsets[vertices, {2}], disallowed]
(* {{"a", "c"}, {"a", "d"}, {"a", "e"}, {"a", "f"}, {"b", "c"}, 
    {"b", "d"}, {"b", "e"}, {"b", "f"}, {"c", "e"}, {"c", "f"}, 
    {"d", "e"}, {"d", "f"}} *)
```

We can get all combinations with `Subsets[possibleContractions]`. However, given a vertex, we may only contract it with one other vertex, not multiple one. Thus, we need a helper function to detect multiple contractions:

```
disjointQ[list_] := Length[Union @@ list] == Length[Join @@ list]
```

These are the allowed contractions: `Select[Subsets[possibleContractions], disjointQ]`.

```
IGVertexContract[g0, #, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram"] & /@ 
 Select[Subsets[possibleContractions], disjointQ]
```

Here's a screenshot of the first few results:

[image]

Note that graphs with reciprocal edges are also generated. You did not make it clear if you need them. If not, just filter them out.